# Modal presentation of UITableViewController from UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

So as per title, I'm trying to present a UITableViewController from a UITabBarController. If you look at the video I've attached, on the third tab, it presents a view controller modally. Which is what I want to achieve.

https://vid.me/B0oy

I've been searching all day for a [solution](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-do-you-show-a-modal-view-controller-when-a-uitabbarcontroller-tab-is-tapped), and I yet I've tried them, but it doesn't work.

This is currently how I do it. I add this line of code in the view controller of my first tab.

```
self.tabBarController?.delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? UITabBarControllerDelegate
```

And this is inside my AppDelegate.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController is YourViewController {
        if let newVC = tabBarController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourVCStoryboardIdentifier") {
            tabBarController.presentViewController(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

func setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {
    guard  let statusBar = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBarWindow")?.valueForKey("statusBar") as? UIView else {
        return
    }

        statusBar.backgroundColor = color
    }

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    setStatusBarBackgroundColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor())
    return true
}
```

Comment: What is current behavior? You haven't mentioned

Comment: Did you debug to see if `shouldSelectViewController` gets called? Your setup is unusual. You shouldn't be doing this in your `AppDelegate`. I would create a class that inherits `UITabBarController` and set up the delegate in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @NightFury The current behavior it loads my view controller as per normal, and it is not doing anything at all

Comment: @grimfrog I'm following the setup based on the link I've provided. I did debug the shouldSelectViewController, however it doesn't get called. Actually I did also create a new class and inherit the main tabbar, however it is giving the same effect.